# Find top most added associates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following classes,

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_calendars, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user

end



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :user_calendars


end

class UserCalendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to be able to find the top n-number of events that belong to the most usercalendars

I have created the following function to get the count of how many users  had added it to a usercalendar.

```
@count = UserCalendar.where('event_id = ?', event_id).count
```

I'm still still just not sure what the best way of getting  the top added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give the `event_id` present n number of times

```
select *,count(*) as count from user_calendar group by event_id having count(*) = n order by count desc
```

Implementing in Rails

```
# Replace n with yours
event_ids = UserEvent.find_by_sql("select *,count(*) as count from user_calendar group by event_id having count(*) = n order by count desc").map(&:id) rescue []

Event.where("id in (?)",event_ids)
```

**Note:** From my understanding you want the event_ids occurred n no of times in `UserEvent`. If I was wrong drop a comment.